# Intent application/msword does not work - how to fix that?

Tags: android, android-intent, ms-word, actionview

I'm trying to visualize some files that come from a URL link: http: //. I have the permission to access them, however, not all of them are being viewed correctly. The files type .rar .docx / doc .xls / xlsx .pptx / ppt are the ones that can not be visualized and make app crash when i clicked the listener, however these others are visualized .pdf .png / jpg / gif and .txt

This is the code I'm using, finding in a post where it was explained how to do exactly what I was looking for:

```
                             Uri urix = Uri.parse(url);
                             Intent intentx = new Intent();
                             intentx.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );

                            if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
                                // Word document
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "application/msword");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
                                // PDF file
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "application/pdf");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
                                // Powerpoint file
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
                                // Excel file
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
                                // WAV audio file
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "application/x-wav");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
                                // RTF file
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "application/rtf");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
                                // WAV audio file
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "audio/x-wav");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
                                // GIF file
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "image/gif");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
                                // JPG file
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "image/jpeg");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
                                // Text file
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "text/plain");
                            } else if (url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
                                // Video files
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "video/*");
                            } else {
                                // Other files
                                intentx.setDataAndType(urix, "*/*");
                            }
                            intentx.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(intentx);
```

I have tried with intentx.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);

Comment: The file types you list require the Microsoft Office application (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) in order to display the files, or an environment that's correctly able to interpret the complex binary or Office Open XML file formats. Apparently, the "viewer" you're trying to use is not able to correctly interpret these file formats...

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, i have installed those applications from microsoft.  Only if the file is local does it try to open and yet launch an error that suggests downloading the file before opening it, in the best case I need to download it from the URL